# How do I get certain columns from a dataset in Apache Spark (pyspark)?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataset with four columns of data.

Ex:

```
a  b  c  d
1, 2, 3, 4
```

...

Using pyspark, how can I retrieve the data for columns `a` and `b` only? I'm new to spark and have tried many things including:

```
 dataset = data_raw.filter(lambda line: line != dataset_header) \
.map(lambda line: line.split(", ", maxsplit=2)).take(1)
```

But this doesn't seem to give me the required objective. All I want is to have columns `a` and `b` and discard the rest of the dataset. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that code would do what you are expecting had it worked. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) for `split` for a little clarity. Here is a simple exapmle:

```
my_string = '1, 2, 3, 4'
result = my_string.split(', ', maxsplit=2)

print(result)
['1', '2', '3, 4']
```

As you can see you end up with three elements as you split on only the first two instances of ', '.

That little detail aside have you tried:

```
dataset = data_raw.filter(lambda line: line != dataset_header) \
    .map(lambda line: line.split(', ')[:2])
```

**EDIT**

In response to your comment, I just loaded a spark RDD with your example data and tested. Below is an image of the result.

[image: pyspark map example]

**EDIT2**

Seeing as you noted that your data is in a csv, you can just use [`SparkSession.read.csv`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SparkSession.read). Once you have the dataframe you can just select your columns:

df['a', 'b'].show(5)

Would show the first five rows.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Grr I have just tried your suggestion, it just prints out all the data.

Comment: @xn139 I just uploaded an image of my test for this. If you can provide some more details about how you are loading your data, using RDD or DF, etc.. it would make it easier to help out.

Comment: Hi @Grr, my data is in a CSV file - when I try parallelizing my CSV file I get this: `TypeError: 'RDD' object is not iterable` Can I parallelize my CSV file and perform the above action?

Comment: If you have a csv just use spark.read.csv(filename) then its almost like pandas.

Comment: many thanks - all working now. I was running an earlier version of spark so the .read.csv() methods weren't available.

Answer (score 2):

Have you try out `Select` method for selecting only two column..

```
dataset.select('a','b').show()
```

I think you should use csv reader for tour dataset.

```
sc.textFile("file.csv") \
.map(lambda line: line.split(",")) \
.filter(lambda line: len(line)<=1) \
.collect()
```